# Masonry messing with bootstrap column size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm trying to achieve this kind of a view with bootstrap + masonry:

[image]

Bootstrap works fine - if I do `col-3-md` in each then 4 show in a row. The problem is that when I add in masonry, they no longer respect that - so `col-3-md` starts showing up with 3 in a row with a blank spot where the 4th would be.

So regular bootstrap looks like this:
[image]

Then when I add Masonry it looks like this:
[image]

Here's my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- regular bootstrap -->
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-large"></div>
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-large"></div>

    <!-- masonry + bootstrap -->
    <div id="masonry-container">
        <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
        <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
        <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
        <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-large"></div>
        <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
        <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-large"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How I'm adding masonry:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#masonry-container').masonry
    itemSelector: '.item'
  return
```

And the CSS:

```
.border {
    border: 1px solid #C7C5C5;
}

.height-short {
    height: 8em;
}

.height-medium {
    height: 16em;
}

.height-large {
    height: 20em;
}
```

Any idea what I need to do so that masonry doesn't change the width of the bootstrap columns?

Comment: Have you tried this: `<div id="masonry-container" class="row">` ?

Comment: you're a flipping genius. that totally worked!

Comment: Just for my knowledge - why did that solve it/what would having the separate masonry div underneath cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap columns should be nested inside `row` div in order to have the proper padding and width.
So the code should be something like:

```
<!-- masonry + bootstrap -->
<div id="masonry-container" class="row">
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-large"></div>
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-medium"></div>
    <div class="item border col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height-large"></div>
</div>
```

I suggest you read [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/) nice tutorial on the bootstrap grid system.